# How to mutate a struct while also using a value produced by struct's immutable method in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
pub enum Lexem<'a> {
    Identifier(&'a str),

}

pub struct Cursor<'a> {
    lexems: Vec<&'a str>,
    offset: usize }

impl<'a> Cursor<'a> {
    pub fn new(lexems: Vec<&str>) -> Cursor {
        Cursor {
            lexems,
            offset: 0
        }
    }

    pub fn peek(&self) -> Option<&str> {
        if self.offset < self.lexems.len() {
            Some(&self.lexems[self.offset])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    pub fn take(&mut self) -> Option<&str> {
        if let Some(lexem) = self.peek() {
            self.offset += 1;
            Some(lexem)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

}
```

But the compiler complains about modifying self.offset inside take() because immutable function peek() was called before. Here's the error the compiler produces:

```
    error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.offset` because it is borrowed
  --> <source>:28:13
   |
26 |     pub fn take(&mut self) -> Option<&str> {
   |                 - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
27 |         if let Some(lexem) = self.peek() {
   |                              ---- `self.offset` is borrowed here
28 |             self.offset += 1;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `self.offset` is assigned to here but 
it was already borrowed
29 |             Some(lexem)
   |             ----------- returning this value requires that `*self` 
is borrowed for `'1`
```

I realise that the error is caused by me returning a result of immutable method which holds references to the internals of the Cursor struct. As far as I understand the compiler assumes that the result of peek() might become invalidated by modifications made to offset, however I know for sure that it actually wouldn't. Therefore, how can I make compiler beliveve that I know what I am doing and allow code like this or similar to this to compile?

Comment: Try typing the return value as `Option<&'a str>` in both places.

Comment: Here's a nice blog post on this kind of problem: [After NLL: Interprocedural conflicts](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2018/11/01/after-nll-interprocedural-conflicts/)

Comment: In this case, you can avoid the conflict using Dogbert's solution. The return values don't actually borrow from `Cursor`, so the return value lifetimes should reflect that.